# DynamicAllocation enabled with Spark on Kubernetes?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Latest [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html) for spark 2.4.5 suggests "Dynamic Resource Allocation and External Shuffle Service" in Future work, however, I have also found some [older documentation](https://apache-spark-on-k8s.github.io/userdocs/running-on-kubernetes.html) for spark 2.2.0 suggesting it is supported after setting up external shuffle service.

**Have you successfully enabled Spark dynamic allocation on Kubernetes? If so, what challenges did you face and which documentation did you reference?**

We are currently using AWS EMR service for Spark, and would like to try out Spark on Kubernetes with Dynamic Allocation enabled.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the older docs do belong to the [older Spark fork repo](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark), which has been used as a basement and POC for the main Apache Spark repository work related to K8s. If you want to have this feature enabled your you - you are restricted to use only this older Spark 2.2.0 fork. Note that it is not recommended for PROD.